# Athena ResultReuseConfiguration in Nodejs Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have an implementation in python to use Athena within a lambda function. There I configured the Athena caching via ResultReuseConfiguration. This works as expected:

```
import boto3

athena = boto3.client('athena', region_name='eu-central-1')   

const query = "...";

queryStart = athena.start_query_execution(
  QueryString = query,
  WorkGroup = "my_workgroup",
  QueryExecutionContext = {
    'Database' : 'my_database',
    'Catalog' : 'my_catalog',
  },
  ResultConfiguration = {
    'OutputLocation': 's3://athena-dev-ai-0000-01/jupyter_notebook'
  },
  ResultReuseConfiguration={
    'ResultReuseByAgeConfiguration': {
       'Enabled': True,
    }
  })
```

I did the same in a nodejs18 implementation:

```
import {
  AthenaClient,
  StartQueryExecutionCommand,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-athena';

const athena = new AthenaClient({ region: 'eu-central-1' });

const query = "...";

const params = {
  QueryString: query, 
  QueryExecutionContext: {
    Database: 'my_database',
    Catalog: 'my_catalog',
  },
  WorkGroup: 'my_workgroup',
  ResultConfiguration : {
    OutputLocation: 'my_location'
  },
  ResultReuseConfiguration:{
    ResultReuseByAgeConfiguration: {
       Enabled: true,
    }
  }
};

const queryExecution = await athena.send(new StartQueryExecutionCommand(params));
```

However, while the python implementation works and reuses the query result in case the query is the same, the nodejs implementation does not do it. This I verify in the Athena AWS Console "Recent queries"

Is there anything I need to check in regards of the version of nodejs and the aws-sdk?

Comment: In the meantime I got the code running for nodejs14 and also there it works totally fine. I didn't read anything that ResultReuseConfiguration is not available for nodejs18. Anyone here who can verify?